# extract sublist of dataframes from list of dataframes based on condition

Tags: r, regex, list, dataframe, sublist

I have a large list of data frames, and I want to create sub lists containing the data frames that fill a condition. Each data frame of the list has the same column names, and they have a column called treatment, which contains the word ZEO or BLEO.  I'd like to be able to write a function or a one-liner that allows me to extract all the dataframes that have "ZEO". (note that one dataframe has only one treatment in it, so all the rows of the ListofData$dataframe1$treatment are equal to ZEO), The list is large (~300 dataframes) and I have other variables I'd like to be able to extract. So far I tried these methods but they didn't seem to work

```
cond<- sapply(ListofData, function(x) x$treatment == "ZEO") 
test <- ListofData[(cond)]
```

The name of the dataframes also contain the information about the treatment, that's why I tried this,but it returns an empty list

```
test<-ListofData[grep('^[Zeo]+',ListofData)]
```

Can you please help me to find a way to extract the data frames I need?

Comment: Maybe try `ListofData_ZEO <- lapply(ListofData, function(x) x[ x$treatment == "ZEO", ] ) ` or `ListofData_ZEO <- ListofData[grepl('^[Zeo]+', names(ListofData)) ]`

Comment: @zx8754     `ListofData_ZEO <- ListofData[grepl('^[Zeo]+', names(ListofData)) ] ` doesn't work, however     `ListofData_ZEO <- lapply(ListofData, function(x) x[ x$treatment == "ZEO", ] )`     almost does the job! It gives me a list where all the dataframes I need are good and the others that i don't need are still in the list but are empty. Any idea how to make them disappear? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using regex should work, see this example:

```
#example data
ListofData <- list(ZEO1 = data.frame(xx = 1, treatment = "ZEO"),
                   xx1 = data.frame(xx = 2, treatment = "xx"),
                   ZEO2= data.frame(xx = 3, treatment = "ZEO"))

#using regex 
res <- ListofData[ grepl("^[Zeo]+", names(ListofData)) ]
res 
# $ZEO1
#   xx treatment
# 1  1       ZEO
# 
# $ZEO2
#   xx treatment
# 1  3       ZEO
```

Here is another solution using column values, this returns empty dataframes, which we exclude using `nrow` and subset:

```
# using lapply, then filter
res <- lapply(ListofData, function(x) x[ x$treatment == "ZEO", ] )
res <- res[ sapply(res, nrow) > 0 ]
res
# $ZEO1
#   xx treatment
# 1  1       ZEO
# 
# $ZEO2
#   xx treatment
# 1  3       ZEO
```